# Empty oAuth Login Dialog

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Back in January I started this project of mine, but I left it mid Jan because of work load.

I retake just recently. When I left it, I got it working login in to facebook both using the standard javascript sdk and when I moved on to Parse to test it online. fast forward to yesterday and I'm finding that whenever I try to login, the oAuth modal dialog never loads, its left blank

I checked the [login SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2), the [parse FB login SDK](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#fbusers) but I'm still having this problem

[image: oAuth Empty Dialog]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, looks like the user scope of email is no longer 'user_email'.